# php + mysql + how to add a comma to split the string in the database

Tags: php, mysql, explode, implode

i am creating a friend request page that it need to take the friends request as an array  than separate  each username  by a comma.

i do not know what to use the implode or the explode  i did use both but neither one  give me the result as i want

when i press the accpet button i get this error

**Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\wamp\www\Unnamed Site 2\resources\friend_requests.php on line 59**

can anyone help me ???

## friend_request.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if($sessionlogin = isset($_SESSION['login']))
 {

   $login = ($_SESSION['login']);
   $userid = ($_SESSION['user_id']);
   $login_user = ($_SESSION['username']);
   $fname = ($_SESSION['first_name']);
   $lname = ($_SESSION['last_name']);
   $sessionaddres =($_SESSION['address']);



 // require_once('header.php'); 
 require_once('for members/scripts/connect.php');
  //find friend request
    $findrequests = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friend_requests WHERE user_from = '$login_user'") or die(mysql_error());
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($findrequests);
   if($numrows == 0)
  {

      echo "YOU HAVE no friend Requests at this time";
      $user_from = "";

  }
    else
  {
       while($get_row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($findrequests))
     {
         $id = $get_row['id'];
         $user_to = $get_row['user_from'];
         $user_from = $get_row['user_to'];

            echo '' . $user_from .   '   wants to be  friend' . '<br />';


            //var_dump($user_from);
            //var_dump($user_to);
            //echo "your user_to is '$user_to'";
            //echo "your user_from is '$user_from'";




?>



<?php

 if(isset($_POST['acceptrequest'.$user_from]))
 {
     //select the friend array  row  from the logged in user
     $get_friend_check = mysql_query("SELECT friend_array FROM user WHERE user_name = '$login_user'") or die(mysql_error());
     $get_friend_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_friend_check);
     $friend_array = $get_friend_row['friend_array'];
     $friendArray_explode = implode(",", $friend_array);
     $friend_array_count = count($friendArray_explode);


     //select the friend array  row from the user  who sent the friend request 
     $get_friend_check_friend = mysql_query("SELECT friend_array FROM user WHERE user_name = '$user_from'") or die(mysql_error());
     $get_friend_row_friend = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_friend_check_friend);
     $friend_array_friend = $get_friend_row_friend['friend_array'];
     $friendArray_explode_friend = implode(",", $friend_array_friend);
     $friend_array_count_friend = count($friendArray_explode_friend);

     if($friend_array == "")
     {
       $friendArray_count = count(NULL);    

     }
        //var_dump($friendArray_count);

    if($friend_array_friend == "")
     {
       $friendArray_count_friend = count(NULL);  
     }

     if (@$friendArray_count == NULL)
     {
         $add_friend_query = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET friend_array = CONCAT(friend_array, '$user_from') WHERE user_name = '$login_user'");
     }

     if(@$friendArray_count_friend == NULL)
     {
         $add_friend_query = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET friend_array = CONCAT(friend_array, '$user_to') WHERE user_name = '$user_from'");
     }
     /*
     if(@$friendArray_count >= 1)
     {
         $add_friend_query = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET friend_array = CONCAT(friend_array, ',$user_from') WHERE user_name = '$login_user'");
     }
     /*
         if(@$friendArray_count_friend >= 1)
         {
         $add_friend_query = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET friend_array = CONCAT(friend_array, ',$user_to') WHERE user_name = '$user_from'");
     }

      */
     // for delete request  

     $delete_request = mysql_query("DELETE FROM friend_requests WHERE user_to = '$user_to' && user_from = '$user_from'") or die(mysql_error());

     echo "YOU are now friends!!";
    //header("Location: friend_requests.php");

 }


 if(isset($_POST['ignorerequest'.$user_from]))
 {
      $ignore_request = mysql_query("DELETE FROM friend_requests WHERE user_to = '$user_to' && user_from = '$user_from'")      or die(mysql_error());

     echo "Request ignored !!";
     header("Location: friend_requests.php");

 }

?><br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<form action="friend_requests.php" method="post">
               <input type="submit" name="acceptrequest<?php echo $user_from; ?>" value="Accept">
               <input type="submit" name="ignorerequest<?php echo $user_from; ?>" value="Ignor">
</form>

<?php
   }
  }
 }

?>
```

Comment: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574)

Comment: @eggyal so how  solve this problem ??

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
      $get_friend_check = mysql_query("SELECT friend_array FROM user WHERE user_name = '$login_user'") or die(mysql_error());

 $your_array = array();
 while ($get_friend_row = mysql_fetch_array($get_friend_check)) {
 $your_array[] = $get_friend_row['friend_array'];
 }

 $friendArray_explode = implode(",", $your_array);
 echo $friendArray_explode;
```

- you could also use implode in mysql directly

like that

```
$get_friend_check = mysql_query("SELECT group_concat(friend_array SEPARATOR ',')
                                 FROM user WHERE user_name = '$login_user'") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: yes i did this code but it did not work still rhe value stored in the database like a one word not separated with a comma

Comment: i tried the code and it display **test2fadysalimYOU are now friends!!**